# returning json data from symfony action with json response

Tags: php, json, symfony

I'm having trouble return the correct json from a controller action.

Right now, I'm using jms serializer to serialize an entity. Like so:

```
$serializedJobOrders = $serializer->serialize($jobOrders, 'json');
```

So I have a string of json that I would like to return. It's actually a json array of objects: [{},{},{}]

Before, I've just used the setContent() method on a response to return json. Like this:

```
$jsonResponse = new JsonResponse();
return $jsonResponse->setContent($serializer->serialize($jobOrders, 'json'));
```

However, there is a security issue with return a json array. It should be an object with an  array in it. Something like {data: [{},{},{}]}. This is where I'm having the trouble though.

I can't just do:

```
return new JsonResponse(array('data' => $serializedJobOrders));
```

because that just creates an escaped string for the 'data' property. I would then have to parse it client-side. I don't think that would be the proper way to do it. To illustrate a bit, this is kind of what it looks like:

{data: "[{\u0022name\u0022: \u0022John\u0022},{\u0022name\u0022: \u0022John\u0022}]"}

How can I return the correct json? So that it looks like this:

```
{data: [
  {'name': 'john'},
  {'name': 'john'},
  {'name': 'john'}
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but it hit me right after that I could just do something like:

```
$data = array('data' => $jobOrders);
$serializedJobOrders = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');
// then just use the setContent() method again
return $jsonResponse->setContent($serializedJobOrders);
```

I truly don't know why it just hit after I spent the time asking this question, doh :)

I am wondering if it is unsafe to use the setContent() method like that though. Seems like it's kind of "raw".

Comment: Maybe the FOSRestBundle could be helpful for you?